# Need to use dd, but no /dev/sd*

Tags: dd, beagleboard

Using Beaglebone.

Need to run `dd` to backup an image and then restore it.

```
dd bs=64K if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/mmcblk1/myImage.img
```

But I don't see any `sdX`, where `X` is a number.

So, what should be the input file path for a full backup?

Comment: What are you trying to backup? A whole disk? A partition? If you run in a terminal `ls -la /dev/sd*` what do you see? Please edit the question posting the output of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Run `lsblk` to see what disks/partitions you have. On the far right  you will see mountpoints, this info will help you with what partition/drive you are trying to make image of.

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0   10G  0 disk 
└─vda1 253:1    0   10G  0 part /
vdb    253:16   0  366K  0 disk
```

Comment: Although you might answer the question by asking about mmc devices, you might consider adding your information requests as comments and not answers.